# Conditional probability formula proof

Tags: conditional-probability

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B) }{P(B)}$$

Is it possible to prove the formula of conditional probability without a venn diagram?

Comment: But this is a *definition*, you don't prove the definitions. You can give examples to show that the definition "makes sense", e.g. using Venn diagrams, or numerical examples, but don't prove them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In usual (modern) probability theory by Kolmogorov used by mostly everyone, this is a definition, hence it does not make sense to prove it.

The base object of the theory is the probability function $A\mapsto P(A)$ whose properties are defined by axioms. Then the function $A,B\mapsto P(A|B)$ is introduced by this definition: $P(A|B)$ is by definition $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$. The intuition/motivation behind this definition can be explained (with the venn diagram for example) but not formally proven.

In alternate probability theories (usually equivalent but expressed differently), it can be an axiom: the base object of the theory is the function $A,B\mapsto P(A|B)$

But it can also be seen as a theorem. Define conditional probability $P(A|B)$ as the probability of the event called $A_B$: "The first time $B$ occurs, $A$ occurs too" in a sequence of repeated independent versions of $(A,B)$. Then it can be proven that $P(A|B)=P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ as a theorem.

Most of this is explained on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_the_probability_of_a_conditional_event).